# Polymorphism with references does not behave as expected

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

As I understand it, polymorphism with references should work exactly as it does with pointers.

However, consider the following example: the calls to `doer()` are correctly dispatched when using pointers, but the "B version" seems to be called in both case when using a reference.

I cannot figure out the reason why the following example is behaving in the way it does. Why is the *"B version"* called in both cases when using a reference?

```
#include <iostream>

class B;
class C;

void doer(B *x) {
    std::cout << "B version" << std::endl;
}

void doer(C *x) {
    std::cout << "C version" << std::endl;
}

class A {
public:
    virtual ~A() {}
    virtual void doit() = 0;
};

class B: public A {
public:
    virtual void doit() override {
        doer(this);
    }
};

class C: public A {
public:
    virtual void doit() override {
        doer(this);
    }
};

int main() {
    B b;
    C c;

    A *a = &b;
    a->doit(); // B version gets called, OK
    a = &c;
    a->doit(); // C version is called, OK

    A &d = b;
    d.doit(); // B version is called, OK
    d = c;
    d.doit(); // B version is called again??
}
```

Comment: `d = c` doesn't reassign the reference. It calls the copy-assignment operator on `A`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

References are bound by their referent for their entire lifetime, and, unlike pointers, require initialization. Using the assignment operator calls the assignment operator of the referent, and does **not** reassign the reference:

```
A &d = b;
d = c;
```

Here `d = c` calls the assignment operator from the base class `A` subobject contained in `d`, and copies the `A` subobject data contained in `c`.

Answer (score 3):

Here you assign a reference:

```
A &d = b;
d.doit(); // B version is called, OK
```

Here you overwrite the object reffered to by d with c (it's no longer the definition of a reference):

```
d = c;
d.doit(); // B version is called again??
```

That's the main difference between references and pointers.  A reference is like a constant pointer that you can only assign at definition.  Afterwards, whenever you use the reference, it means the object you've referred to.

In fact when you do `d = c;` some slicing occurs.  The object d is in fact a B, but the `operator=` from A is called, copying only member data of A.

Here how to demonstrate this statement:

```
class A {
public:
    ...
    A& operator= (A a) {
        cout << "A::operator=" << endl;  // just to show what happens when d=c is called
        return *this; 
    }
};
class B : public A {
public:
    int x;   // add some variables for B
    virtual void doit() override {
        cout << "B::doit() " << x << endl; 
        doer(this);
    }
};
class C : public A {
public:
    int a,b; // add aditional variables for C
    virtual void doit() override {
        cout << "C::doit() " << a << ","<<b << endl;
        doer(this);
     }
};
...
b.x = 123;  // put some class specific variables in C
c.a = 222;  c.b = 333;  // put some class specific variables in C
A &d = b;  // assignement of the reference.  d reffers to a b object
d.doit();  // B version is called, OK
d = c;     // but an A object is copied (so only A subobject of c is taken
           // to overwrite A subobject of d)
d.doit();  // B version is called becaus again?? => yes !! because it's still a B
           // And you see that the B part of the object is left intact by A::operator=
cout << typeid(d).name() << endl; 
           // remember at this point that d still refers to b !
```

Comment: A reference is not a pointer. It can implemented as such, but that's implementation defined.

Comment: @black I completely agree.  I meant that it's **like** a pointer (because this is something that OP seems to master well).  I've edited to avoid any ambiguity here !

Comment: I'd suggest adding this [clarification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-a-pointer-variable-and-a-reference-variable-in) to remove any further doubt, IMHO.

Comment: While the answer is here, it's diluted in a few unnecessary details imho.   @0x499602D2 got the key detail, that assigning to a reference simply calls the assignment operator on the lhs. I know what a reference is, I know what an assignment operator is and how it behaves, I simply didn't realize what was happening.